# Xcode 5 - iOS Error with no visible interface

Tags: ios, uiview

i have problem with this part of code:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *loadstring1 = [defaults objectForKey:@"Save1232"]; 
[Label1232 setText:loadstring1];
```

Xcode shows to me:

> no visible @interface for 'UIView' declarates the selector 'setText:'

It doesnt metter but i put it into `- (void)viewDidLoad`. The problem is that i've used this before without any problems. Right now i cant. Anyone?

Comment: Show us Label1232 declaration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you've defined `Label1232` as a `UIView`, when it should in fact be a `UILabel`.

Comment: Thanks. OMG, i can't believe it  :)

Comment: @BartekWoźniak if the answer solves your problem please accept it by clicking the tick on the left under the voting module.